# Cannot share content to Facebook page's timeline using SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk, slcomposeviewcontroller, fbsdksharekit

When sharing content to Facebook from app using iOS's Social Framework, the share dialog (**SLComposeViewController**) only allows us to share to **MyTimeline/Friends/Group**.

[image: Screenshot]

There is not an option to share to the user's page/business. Is there any way to share to it using just Social share from iOS? I have the option to post to page when using **FBSDKShareKit**, but I just don't want to import heavy FBSDK for just one feature. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (June-22-2017):**

There is no current solution to the question above and to add to it, Apple just mentioned in the [iOS 11 beta 2 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/Beta_Release_Notes_Jun_21_2017/iOS_11_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf) that developers no longer have access to the signed-in social accounts in the phone's Settings. They mentioned it in their **Known issues**, but not sure if that's a real deprecation of Social Accounts.

> • Social accounts have been removed from Settings in iOS 11. Third-party apps no longer
>   have access to those signed-in accounts. (31687059)